# copy NSArray inside an empty NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray

I have a first NSArray `firstArray` and I do

```
[firstArray removeAllObjects];
```

after I want fill it with the content of an other array `secondArray`

is it right write in this way?

```
firstArray = secondArray;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `firstArray = secondArray` will reassign the pointers, this is not the behavior you want. You want `[firstArray addObjectsFromArray:secondArray]`

Comment: and if I use initwitharray? what happens?

Comment: You'd be breaking the contract of the object. Objects must only be initialized once, doing it multiple times WILL cause you problems down the road.

Comment: @JoshuaWeinberg What about ```firstArray = [secondArray copy];```?

Answer (score 1):

Since the firstArray is an NSArray, you will want to do this instead:

```
firstArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:secondArray];
```

Comment: and if it's a nsMutableArray?

Comment: If firstArray is an NSMutableArray, you can use the addObjectsFromArray method that Joshua suggested.