# Compare two NSArrays

Tags: objective-c, comparison, nsmutablearray, nsarray, compare

How can I compare two NSArrays so that I can delete everything that isn't in both arrays.

I tried it like this:

```
    NSArray *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", nil]; 
    NSArray *array2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"5",@"6", nil];

    NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array1];
    NSMutableArray *myMutableArrayTwo = [myMutableArray copy];
    [myMutableArray removeObjectsInArray:array2];

    [array1 release];
    [array2 release];

    NSArray *array3 = [myMutableArray copy];
    [myMutableArrayTwo removeObjectsInArray:array3]; // Error here: "SIGABRT"

    NSLog(@"array3:%@",myMutableArrayTwo);
```

But it doesn't work because of the error. It sais: "-[__NSArrayI removeObjectsInArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e51550"

What did I do wrong? Or are there easier ways to solve my problem?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you create a copy (non-mutable) of a NSMutableArray, so you are losing the mutable capabilities.

Use the `mutableCopy` method instead.

By the way, you've got huge memory problems. Your `array1` and `array2` variables are auto-released objects. Releasing them will lead you to problems.

You only need to release the arrays you created with `alloc`, `copy` or `mutableCopy`.

Comment: Thanks that helped. And also thanks for the reminder. I always forget all this memoryManagement things ... should write in Java xD

Comment: i know this is an old question. but i think its confusing, that calling copy on a mutableArray creates an immutableArray. Copy should return a copy of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344563/copy-nsarray-inside-an-empty-nsarray), you should use `addObjectsFromArray` instead of `arrayWithArray` since you are populating a `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:array1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSArray *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", nil]; 

NSArray *array2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"5",@"6", nil];

NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array1];

NSMutableArray *myMutableArrayTwo = [myMutableArray mutableCopy];//mutable copy

[myMutableArray removeObjectsInArray:array2];

//    u didn't use alloc,init,new,copy to create array1,array2.
//    so u dont need to release it.because it is autoreleased object.

//    [array1 release];
//    [array2 release];

NSMutableArray *array3 = [myMutableArray mutableCopy];//mutable copy

[myMutableArrayTwo removeObjectsInArray:array3]; 

NSLog(@"array3:%@",myMutableArrayTwo);
```

**OUTPUT:**
array3:(
        1,
        2
        )

**NOTE: u cannot remove any object from NSArray once created.its immutable.**

```
that's y we have used mutable NSMutableArray
```